# Would a tag for "How to" be useful to attract new users?

Tags: discussion, tags, interesting-tags

I see that when I search for something on Google and it starts with "how to", there are a lot of suggestions like:

- how to prune xyz?
- how to germinate xyz?
- how to take cuttings from xyz?
- how to grow xyz?

Would this tag help us to get on top of Google results? We have many interesting questions and answers on this topics in GL and I understand that retagging would be time-consuming.

Comment: Hi Alina! This doesn't answer the question, but, like @J. Musser showed with an example of his, your own questions come up easily too. For instance, search "What's wrong with my Dypsis lutescens?" and [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30859/what-disease-is-affecting-my-dypsis-lutescens) comes up third. Even just googling "Which Fenestraria?" brings up [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/) question of yours fifth. See what an awesome impact you're having!

Comment: You are right, Sue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each tag needs to cover a specific topic, just like they do now. Tags including 'how-to' would just confuse things and only minimally boost our prominence. And I do see our material quite often in google searches. For example if you search for something about Aloe vera blooming, [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2600/what-conditions-are-necessary-to-make-a-potted-aloe-vera-bloom) one is near the top of the first page. Those things are good to see.

The title and body of the post are also very important in a google search, so remember that when you're writing a question, and be sure to include all the relevant keywords.

I would say, no, don't change the tags.